# Unable to install libpcre3-dev in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, 14.10, dependencies

I am trying to install libpcre3-dev in ubuntu 14.10 and `sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev` gives me the following error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libpcre3-dev :
Depends: libpcre3 (= 1:8.31-2ubuntu2) but 1:8.35-3ubuntu1 is to be
installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when i try `sudo-apt-get install libpcre3` its says that i already have the latest version of libpcre3. So how can i install version 1:8.31 of libpcre3 so that i can solve the dependency issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and update the list package (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) file and add the following line to it:

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-security main
```

After that run:

```
apt-get update
```

And now you can install `libpcre3` 8.35

But please be sure that after installing the package change the (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) to the first situation and remove the line you added. Because it may produce inconsistency to install other packages in future.