# Can't install libpcre3-dev

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install `libpcre3-dev` but it gives me the follwing error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: libpcre3-dev :
>   Depends: libpcre3 (= 2:8.38-3.1) but  2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is to be
>   installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

The `2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` is from an 'old' ppa (ondrej), so I took a fresh and new [Sources.list](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/txt/xenial/sources_a6d5fe414c4019cfe0fb2116e57cbf1c895286e4.txt).

I had the same issue with `php7.0-dev` and ended up uninstalling php7.0 and installing it from the official repos.

Now when I want to remove `libpcre3` it wants to remove nearly all of my packages? Is there another way to "change" the libpcre3 package to the "official" one?

I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736082/unable-to-install-libpcre3-dev-in-ubuntu-14-10), with no luck

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3=2:8.38-3.1 libpcre3-dev=2:8.38-3.1
```

to force `apt-get` to install version 2:8.38-3.1 of those packages.

**Warning:** Only use this this if you are really sure you want to install version *2:8.38-3.1* (the version from the official **Ubuntu 16.04** repository) of the packages `libpcre3` and `libpcre3-dev`.

If you are not running Ubuntu 16.04 you should change the version number to the version you actually want to install.

Comment: This does not work on ubuntu 18.04. 
It gives `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2:8.41-1.1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '2:8.41-1.1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+3'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '2:8.41-1.1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+3'
`

Comment: OMG this just uninstalled my entire PHP distro, including phpmyadmin, mysql, apache and all this other random stuff, and cause my webserver to serve raw code to the browser. Downvoting this answer sorry, can you please provide any links to some relevant knowledge so future punters don't do whatever it is I just did? Ubuntu 18.04LTS btw

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes: I added a warning.  It seems you still have package  sources for 16.04 activated on your system. By forcing to install `libpcre3` from 16.04 APT removed all packages depending on the 18.04 version of `libpcre3`. It's usually a good idea to remove old package sources.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with Ubuntu 22.04.3 and could resolve by simply fixing it with aptitude.

```bash
sudo aptitude install libpcre3-dev
```