# Ubuntu 18.10 Cannot install php7.2-dev for install phpize

Tags: apt, php, 18.10

I'm having still issues with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048568/cannot-install-php7-2-dev-on-ubuntu-18-due-to-unmet-dependencies) on Ubuntu 18.10 with ondrej packages. I want to install php-dev for firebase. When I try to install grpc using pecl It throws me phpize doesn't exist, when I check what I need it is from php7.2-dev. I check held packages but anything on there.

I try to downgrade as you said but appears like explain [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048568/cannot-install-php7-2-dev-on-ubuntu-18-due-to-unmet-dependencies):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version ‘2:8.39-9’ for ‘libpcre3’ was not found
E: Version ‘2:8.39-9’ for ‘libpcre3-dev’ was not found
```

And:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version ‘1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1’ for ‘libssl1.1’ was not found
E: Version ‘1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1’ for ‘libssl-dev’ was not found
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the available sources in the Ununtu repositories for those packages:

```
$ apt-cache madison libpcre3
  libpcre3 |  2:8.39-11 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

Ah, there's the problem. On 18.10, you are telling apt to install -9 instead of -11. You're tying to install an OLDER version that's not in the 18.10 repos. This means you have unwisely added a non-Ubuntu source that is intended for an older release of Ubuntu (like 18.04).

When a release of Ubuntu is built from Debian sources, all the versions are synchronized. All of the thousands of package depend upon a single version of each dependency. And then that one version goes into the repos. That's why Ubuntu is referred to as a *snapshot distro.* When you change versions, you might break all those dependencies. And that's why a release-upgrade involved replacing thousands of packages...all the dependencies must be updated to the new snapshot.

**The problem you have** is caused by trying to add packages with 18.04 dependencies to an 18.10 system. It won't work without expert ongoing maintenance. You can add 18.10 packages to an 18.10 system, or you can add 18.04 packages to an 18.04 system. But you cannot cross versions with the risk of breaking your system quite horribly, so the whole distro, repos, releases, and apt are set up to stop you from doing that.

Now let's take a look at libssl:

```
$ apt-cache madison libssl1.1
 libssl1.1 | 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages
 libssl1.1 | 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security/main amd64 Packages
 libssl1.1 | 1.1.1-1ubuntu2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

Same problem. Version 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1 is in 18.04, not 18.10. You are trying to add 18.04 packages to an 18.10 system. Stop doing that.